# Retrieving data type information for columns in an Oracle OCCI ResultSet

Tags: c++, oracle

After sending a simple query via OCCI (example: select * from ALL_USERS) I'm in the need to know the datatype for the column, for the moment I've been playing with the     **ResultSet::getColumnListMetaData()** method without success.
Questions:
 1. How can I get the datatype by using the aforementioned method and the MetaData class?
 2. Is there any better documentation out there than the one already provided by oracle?

Comment: By something like:  
    MetaData::getString(occi::MetaData::ATTR_TYPECODE);  
I always end up receiving an SQLException with this description: **ORA-31124: Illegal attribute passed**

Answer (score 2):

I've got this old code laying around, I guess it does exactly what you want.  Its using OCI, not OCCI, but maybe it helps.

```
/* Get the number of columns in the query */
ub4 colCount = 0;
oraCheckErr( m_err, OCIAttrGet((dvoid *)_stmt, OCI_HTYPE_STMT, (dvoid *)&colCount,
                    0, OCI_ATTR_PARAM_COUNT, m_err));

ub2 oraType = 0;
OCIParam *col = 0;

ub4 nameLen, colWidth, charSemantics;
text *name;

for (ub4 i = 1; i <= colCount; i++)
{
    /* get parameter for column i */
    oraCheckErr( m_err, OCIParamGet((dvoid *)_stmt, OCI_HTYPE_STMT, m_err, (dvoid**)&col, i));

    /* get data-type of column i */
    oraType = 0;
    oraCheckErr( m_err, OCIAttrGet((dvoid *)col, OCI_DTYPE_PARAM,
            (dvoid *)&oraType, 0, OCI_ATTR_DATA_TYPE,  m_err));

    /* Retrieve the column name attribute */
    nameLen = 0;
    oraCheckErr( m_err, OCIAttrGet((dvoid*)col, OCI_DTYPE_PARAM,
            (dvoid**) &name, &nameLen, OCI_ATTR_NAME, m_err ));

    /* Retrieve the length semantics for the column */
    charSemantics = 0;
    oraCheckErr( m_err, OCIAttrGet((dvoid*)col, OCI_DTYPE_PARAM,
            (dvoid*) &charSemantics,0, OCI_ATTR_CHAR_USED, m_err ));

    colWidth = 0;
    if (charSemantics)
        /* Retrieve the column width in characters */
        oraCheckErr( m_err, OCIAttrGet((dvoid*)col, OCI_DTYPE_PARAM,
                (dvoid*) &colWidth, 0, OCI_ATTR_CHAR_SIZE, m_err ));
    else
        /* Retrieve the column width in bytes */
        oraCheckErr( m_err, OCIAttrGet((dvoid*)col, OCI_DTYPE_PARAM,
                (dvoid*) &colWidth,0, OCI_ATTR_DATA_SIZE, m_err ));

    _elements.output.push_back( SQLElement( String(reinterpret_cast<char*>(name), nameLen), getSQLTypes( oraType ), i, colWidth ));
}

OCIHandleFree ( (dvoid*) _stmt, OCI_HTYPE_STMT );
```

*EDIT:* As per ypour request:

```
SQLTypes getSQLTypes(ub2 _oracleType)
{
switch( _oracleType )
{
    case SQLT_INT:
        return stInt;
    case SQLT_FLT:
    case SQLT_BDOUBLE:
        return stDouble;
    case SQLT_BFLOAT:
        return stFloat;
    case SQLT_ODT:
        return stDate;

    case SQLT_DATE:
    case SQLT_TIMESTAMP:
    case SQLT_TIMESTAMP_TZ:
    case SQLT_TIMESTAMP_LTZ:
        return stTimeStamp;

    case SQLT_CHR:
    case SQLT_NUM:
    case SQLT_STR:
    case SQLT_VCS:
    default:
        return stText;
}
}
```

Comment: I thought the datatype was coming as a string and instead it is coming as an integer (in OCCI land), so instead of getString(occi::MetaData::ATTR_DATA_TYPE) by using a getInt() at least don't get an error message, however, I don't know how to match the numeric code to a proper oracle data type, perhaps your getSQLTypes has the answer?
Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use method:

```
MetaData::getInt(occi::MetaData::ATTR_DATA_TYPE);
```

and compare returned value with constants from enumeration of possible types which you can find in occiCommon.h:

```
enum Type { OCCI_SQLT_CHR=SQLT_CHR, OCCI_SQLT_NUM=SQLT_NUM  ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't add a comment due to low reputation.
In case someone is interested in an OCCI example based on the answer by Pustovalov Dmitry.

```
auto results = statement->executeQuery(selectCommand);
auto columnMetaData = results->getColumnListMetaData();
while (results->next())
{
    for ( size_t index = 0; index < columnMetaData.size(); ++index )
    {
        // Column Meta data is std::vector - zero based indexing while
        // Oracle result-set getxyz() methods have one based indexing.
        cout << "Column name: " << columnMetaData[index].getString(MetaData::ATTR_NAME) << endl;
        switch(columnMetaData[index].getInt(MetaData::ATTR_DATA_TYPE))
        {
        case OCCI_SQLT_CHR:
            cout << results->getString(index+1) << endl;
            break;
        case OCCI_SQLT_TIMESTAMP:
            cout << results->getTimestamp(index+1).toText("YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS.FF", 0) << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

More details available [here](https://github.com/alexeyvo/oracle_oci_examples/blob/master/occidesc.cpp)