# OCI getting fetched data without knowing the table structure

Tags: c++, c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I´m working for the first time with  OCI so this may be a basic question.... I´m coming from MySql word.... Using VS2012 with C++.

I wish to do a simple SELECT statement with some variations on WHERE and LIMIT clause. The SQL query is build dynamically from a C++ written processor and the statement comes ready from this module. So I may have something like:

`SELECT * FROM MYTABLE3;` or

`SELECT F1, F2, F3 FROM MYTABLE1;` or even

```
SELECT F1, F3, F4 FROM MYTABLE2 WHERE ID > 10;
```

No big deal here.

My problem is that I DON´T KNOW IN ADVANCE THE TABLE FORMAT, so I cannot bind variables to it before executing the statement and fetching the table structure. In MySql that´s easy, because I execute the statement and I get the resultSet. From the resultSet I can check the number of columns retrieved, the name, data format and size of each column. After reading that data I build a dynamic matrix with the table structure and its data, my final goal. Something as:

```
   sql::ResultSetMetaData *resultMeta = resultSet->getMetaData();

    while (resultSet->next())
    {
         for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= resultMeta->getColumnCount(); i++) 
         {
             std::string label = resultMeta->getColumnLabel(i);
             std::string type = resultMeta->getColumnTypeName(i);
             // ... Get the resultset attributes and data
         }

         retData.push_back(data); 
     }
```

From what I´ve seen in Oracle, I need to bind the variables that are going to be returned *before* issuing the execute/fetch operations. In my case I cannot do it because I don´t know the table structure in advance...

I´m pretty sure Oracle can do that, I just don´t know how to do it. I´ve read the Oracle Docs and did not find references to it....

Help is very much appreciated and code examples also. I´m stuck with that for 2 days now... Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following on your statement handle ( stmhp). This will give you column count on your oracle statement.

err = OCIAttrGet ((dvoid *)stmhp, (ub4)OCI_HTYPE_STMT, (dvoid *) 
                  &parmcnt, (ub4 *) 0, (ub4)OCI_ATTR_PARAM_COUNT, errhp);

Please check this link also which will help you to find out data type of every column in the resultset.

[Retrieving data type information for columns in an Oracle OCCI ResultSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338092/retrieving-data-type-information-for-columns-in-an-oracle-occi-resultset)